# Option similar to `vc-directory-exclusion-list` but for files create by build tools

Tags: files, projectile, project

I'm missing an option variable similar to `vc-directory-exclusion-list` that holds of a list of auto-generated directory names that contain temporary files that are typically but not exlusively created by build tools.

For instance the D official build tool [dub](https://github.com/dlang/dub) creates a directory `.dub` storing generated code and binary artifacts.

I could add `.dub` to the `vc-directory-exclusion-list` for now but I have the feeling I might run into trouble doing so.

Two named contenders of such a variable could be either

- `temporary-directory-exclusion-list` or
- `generated-directory-exclusion-list`

.

Alternatively `project.el` could be extended with a variable similar to

`projectile-globally-ignored-directories`

but I'm not sure this feature should be restricted to projects only.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about `project.el` and its built-in VC-based backend, have you tried customizing `project-vc-ignores`?

You can change its global value, or you can put different (per-project) values inside corresponding `.dir-locals.el` files.

And if you wanted to see it affect non-project related commands, you could try to give more examples of such.

Also see `grep-find-ignored-directories` and its definition.

Comment: I was primarily interested in a setting that affected non-project/vc logic aswell. And I think generalizing `vc-directory-exclusion-list` is the right solution there. But this solves my issue right now, thanks.